# FacesEvent lose focus on field

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have a ValueChangeListener associated to a field in my jsf view. When I change the value of the field, and click onto another field, after processing the ValueChangeEvent the focus is lost.

In the event listener I do something like:

```
if (PhaseId.ANY_PHASE.equals(vce.getPhaseId())) {
        vce.setPhaseId(PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES);
        vce.getComponent().queueEvent(vce);
    } else {logic}
```

so I queue the event in another phase. I've noticed that if I don't requeue the event, the focus is mantained.
Also I noticed that if I queue the event on PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW phase, the ValueChangeListener is not called again in that phase.
I don't understand why or how I lose the focus if I requeue the event. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That are two questions at once: `RESTORE_VIEW` is the first phase - in your event listener you are most likely already after that phase. You loose the focus in a JSF application if you either open a new page or refresh the part of the page using AJAX which has the focus. So you are most likely refreshing the field if you call _logic_.

Comment: But if I don't requeue the event, the focus still persist on the next field also if I execute logic. The focus lost appear only if I requeue the event (also if I don't execute logic).

Comment: Without more information about the JSF page it is hard to tell, what leads to the refresh. You could at least look at the ajax response in your browser (network connections tab in any dev tool) to confirm that the focused field is part of the refresh.

Comment: You were right. The field losing focus get updated in consequence of Converter and Validator associated to the field. Thank you @TobiasLiefke